# Is it possible to make a TileMap that adjust it self to multiple screens?

Tags: tilemap, tiled

I need to build a tile map that is supposed to fit nicely in several screen Sizes.
However, `Tiled` the tile map editor I use allows only to produce absolute fixed size tile maps.

**Is there an easy way to make adaptable tile maps or should I build one for each screen size?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect the tile map to adapt to the screen size? If you need it to adapt in a way that requires rearranging tiles or using different map dimensions, then you won't generally get around building multiple maps.

However, most commonly this is done by scaling and/or having a part of the map that is optional go out of the screen at the edges. And if the difference in resolutions is very large, swapping in higher or lower resolution graphics as appropriate. These techniques are independent of tile maps.

Here is an article about this: http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-different-screen-sizes/.